# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/mydatabase

Tags: eclipse, servlets, java-8, mariadb, connector-j

I have mariadb 10.4 running on my system. The db connection is good, i have tested with db workbench with the root password.
On the other hand, I try to connect to it from my Java code,  i have the exception below:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/mydatabase
```

My java code is as below:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class CountryDAO {


    public void list() throws SQLException{
        String databaseURL = "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/mydatabase";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "root";

        try 
        {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL, user, password);

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw ex;
        }      


    }
}
```

I am calling this code from a servlet.
I am using eclipse and i have added the mariadb-java-client-2.4.2.jar as external jar from build path. It should be working but it doesn't.

**UPDATE**: Firstly, I have tested my code in a new Eclipse Java project and it works like a charm. Secondly, i have tried to call the same method from a main method of another class, the db connection also work perfectly. So i guess my problem is because i call this connection from a Servlet. I don't know why it does so but i am kind of stuck.  Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You have to load the driver first.

```
Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
```

Comment: actually, it is not needed anymore. This is the legacy way, check https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/about-mariadb-connector-j/

Comment: I have updated my question, do you have any other idea?

Comment: Actually, after several modification and test, it worked with this declaration. But i had tried this declaration, yesterday, it hadn't worked. The thing is that now if i call this method from a different class, Class.forName declaration is not needed. I am kind of confused.

Comment: Wow it works now even doc said it is not needed~~